# Properties of base change of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over a field $K$. Let's assume that $X$ is integral. Now let $L$ be any field extension of $K$ and let's construct the variety:

$$X_L:= X\times_{\operatorname{Spec K}} \operatorname{Spec L}$$
Which one of the following statements is true?

1. $X_L$ projective $\Rightarrow$ $X$ projective
2. $X_L$ affine $\Rightarrow$ $X$ affine
3. $X_L$ quasi-projective $\Rightarrow$ $X$ quasi-projective

I wasn't able to find an explicit answer to those question, but it seems that 1. and 2. are true, whereas 3. is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertion 1. is true by EGA II, Corollaire 6.6.5, page 132.
The proof assumes that $[L:K]\lt \infty$ but Grothendieck-Dieudonné claim that the result remains true for an infinite extension field, and that this will be proved in Chapter V.
That chapter never was published, but fortunately Ulrich has given a proof on mathoverflow  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/1591/450).

Assertion 2. is true and proved in Görtz-Wedhorn's [Algebraic Geometry I](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-8348-9722-0) by : Proposition 14.51 (6), page 442.

Assertion 3. Our ever attentive friend Alex Youcis remarks that I had overlooked that Grothendieck-Dieudonné also prove that the result for Assertion 1. is true with "projective" replaced by "quasi-projective", so that your implication 3. is  true.
The proof they give is valid only for finite extension fields $K\subset L$ and they refer to the future Chapter V for the general case.
Since that tome never appeared you'll have to check whether Ulrich's proof on mathoverflow can be adapted from the projective to the quasi-projective case.

Comment: (+1) Dear Georges, IIRC the method of proof for the case when $[L:K]<\infty$ to show projectivity is to show that the norm of ample is ample. Can one then not use the fact that quasi-projective is the same thing as being finite type and having an ample invertible sheaf to show that the same result holds for quasi-projective? Then proceed as in Gortz's linked MO answer?

Comment: @SamirCanning Note that the question is not about whether or not a property is preserved by base change, but whether or not you can *descend* the property after (suitable base change). In other words, the type of question you can ask is if $X\to Y$ is a morphism and if $T\to Y$ is a 'suitable cover' of $Y$ such that $X_T\to T$ has property P, does $X\to Y$ have property $P$? The correct StacksProject link would then be something more like Tag02YJ. Unfortunately, neither projective nor quasi-projective are fpqc local on the base (see Tag 08J0). But, specifically for field extensions they're OK.

Comment: Dear Georges, in fact looking at the referenced EGA result it looks like they do just that--they actually state the result for both projective and quasi-projective: "Soient $X$ un préschéma de type fini sur un corps $K$, $K'$ une extension
de degré fini de $K$. Pour que $X$ soit projectif (resp. quasi-projectif} sur $K$, il faut et il suffit que $X'= X\otimes_K K'$ soit projectif (resp. quasi-projectif) sur $K'$." Hopefully I haven't made a mistranslation.

Comment: Dear @Alex: as usual your comment is absolutely correct and  relevant. Thank you very much for your insight: I have added your remark to the answer and am very grateful to you since now the OP's question has been completely answered (I completely trust that Grothendieck and Dieudonné had a solid proof if they said they had!)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It seems that Ulrich's proof for a generic extension uses properness, so I cannot use it for the quasi-projective case.

Comment: Dear Dubious: you are right. You'll have to trust Grothendieck-Dieudonné for the time being (no problem there I think), or find a proof yourself, or hope that a user will give a  reference (or sketch a proof).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I found the complete reference: Gortz-wedhorn proposition 14.55.  It proves what I wanted.

Comment: Well done, Dubious. Bravo!